# Applying portable bit masks and flags in C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I develop firmware for embedded systems using various microcontroller architectures/word sizes and try to emphasize portability when I can. My question is about generating/applying bit masks and flags that is safe and portable, and for any non-universal code, what would the corner cases be.

**Bit masks**

```
#define MASK_8_V1(x) ((x) & 0xFF)
#define MASK_8_V2(x) ((x) & 0x00FF)

a = MASK_8_V1(b)
a = MASK_8_V2(b)
```

Are these always guaranteed to get the value of a's width where all bits are zero'd out except the lower 8 from b? Is there any difference between the 2 versions since they should be signed extended if necessary?

**Flags**

```
#define GEN_FLAG_16(x) ((0xFFFF) & ((unsigned) 1 << (x)))
#define GEN_FLAG_32(x) ((0xFFFFFFFF) & ((unsigned long) 1 << (x)))
```

If I need a generic macro for generating flag constants, will this always result in a flag constant for the listed width?

**Both**

```
#define CHECK_FLAG_16(x, y) ((x) & GEN_FLAG_16(y))
#define CHECK_FLAG_32(x, y) ((x) & GEN_FLAG_32(y))

if(CHECK_FLAG_16(a, b))
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Combining the previous scenarios, will this always execute the inner code if the desired bit in b's original value is set?

For all cases, assume:

- C90 or C99 compliant compiler
- a and b can be any arbitrary combination of native C types, signed or unsigned
- x always evaluates to a positive integer type
- arbitrary native word size

Edit for those mentioning the use of `stdint.h`: I recently came across an issue where we needed to port a serial protocol handler I had written over to another microcontroller family, only to discover that RAM was not byte addressable. We ended up removing all uses of uint8_t and made modifications to work with 16-bit addressable memory. This got me wondering if I could have implemented it differently with native C types to avoid later modification. My questions came indirectly from that problem.

Comment: What compilers did you try?  what happened when you tried them.  And specs did you read with respect to these?  And what did they say?

Comment: Why do you thing `0xff` is any different from `0x00000000ff`? And any reason you don't use fixed width types which are specifically defined for fixed width data? See `stdint.h`! As a side-note: don't use signed integers.

Comment: You have two statements which kinda contradict each other: 1. I try to emphasize portability when I can. 2. I'm only interested in the lower 8 bits of a value.

Comment: @Olaf We actually do enforce the use of `stdint.h` at my workplace, and all code developed in recent years has followed this. I recently came across an issue where we needed to port a serial protocol handler I had written over to another microcontroller family, only to discover that RAM was not byte addressable. We ended up removing all uses of uint8_t and made modifications to work with 16-bit addressable memory. This got me wondering if I could have implemented it differently with native C types to avoid later modification. My questions came indirectly from that problem.

Comment: @Olaf Good catch, I missed adding `unsigned`.

Comment: Why are you not using functions? These problems would not occur if you did.

Comment: "that RAM was not byte addressable" - This is not possible in C. Memory is always `char`/byte-addressable. But note a byte is not the same as "8 bits". Read the standard which types have to be available and which are optional. If the memory uses 16 bit bytes, you don't have `uint8_t`, but should have `uint16_t`, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these always guaranteed to get the value of a's width where all bits are zero'd out except the lower 8 from b?

Yes.

The resulting type of the macro might be different though, depending on what type `b` is. This could cause portability issues. Therefore it would be best to cast the result to the intended type, for example `uint32_t`.

> Is there any difference between the 2 versions

No they are equivalent.

> they should be signed extended if necessary

It usually doesn't make any sense to use bit-wise operators on signed types.

> If I need a generic macro for generating flag constants, will this always result in a flag constant for the listed width?

Yes, but the result will have a different type depending on size of int or long.

> I recently came across an issue where we needed to port a serial protocol handler I had written over to another microcontroller family, only to discover that RAM was not byte addressable.

That's mainly the compiler's problem. Also, it isn't clear how `uint8_t` would be a problem on such systems, there is always implicit integer promotion. Sounds rather like you had some algorithm problem, maybe code using `uint8_t*` pointers or something like that.

---

Pedantically, fully portable code would look something like:

```
#define MASK8_32(x) ((uint32_t)(x) & 0xFFul)

#define GEN_FLAG_16(x) (uint16_t)( 0xFFFFu & (1u << (x)) )
#define GEN_FLAG_32(x) (uint32_t)( 0xFFFFFFFFu & (1ul << (x)) )
```

Now most of the potential size-of-int and implicit type promotion reliances have been removed.

---

Main portability concerns here are:

- Your code relies on the size of `int` and `long` Such code is non-portable, because those types may have any size. Using the fixed-width integer types from stdint.h *will* solve a lot of these problems.
- Your code is unaware of signedness of default types and integer literals. In many cases you use bit-wise operators on signed operands, which is always a bad idea.
- You seem generally unaware of how implicit type promotions work in C.

As it turns out, all of these problems can be solved by [MISRA-C](http://www.misra-c.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx). I'd recommend buying MISRA-C:2012 and reading it for education purposes.

---

As a side note, code like `a = OBSUCRE_MACRO(b);` is *far less readable* than code like `a = b & 0xFF;`. Because you can always assume that the reader is a C programmer, and as such knows the C language, but does not know your private, secret macro language.

In addition, function-like macros are unsafe and should be avoided when possible.

So I question what good these macros do in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Regarding the non-byte-addressable issue, you are correct, it was from using `uint8_t *` to parse byte streams for serial communications. How would you remove that dependency? As for obscure macros, I agree it can be unnecessary. I sometimes use these to enforce consistency, but maybe this one is a poor case. A case where it can make more sense is something like `#define CHECK_INCLUSIVE(val, min, max) (((val) >= (min)) && ((val) <= (max)))`. It removes the possibility of making a hard-to-find typo with the comparison operators.

Comment: @ohitsderrick There's not much you can do against unaligned access unless the compiler has implemented some smart work-around for it. That is, when you write C code that says "read 1 byte at address 0x1001", the compiler needs to generate code "read 1 word at address 0x1000, mask out one byte".

Comment: @ohitsderrick Regarding that macro, it would seem that making a typo or bug when writing that macro is far easier to do than when writing the simple line `if(val>=min && val<=max)`...

Answer (score -1):

What you should really do is use types defined in `<stdint.h>`.  You know exactly how many bits you need for your flags, so you choose the appropriate datatype.  For example:

```
#define GEN_FLAG_8(x) ((uint8_t)(1 << (x)))
#define GEN_FLAG_16(x) ((uint16_t)(1 << (x)))
```

You could also opt for the same guarantees but potentially larger datatypes with `uint_fast16_t` etc.

It's worth mentioning that you should make macros or functions to do the masking as well, so you avoid peppering your code with integer literals.

Comment: Yes, good point on the masking macro. I modified my original question for consistency. As a side note, casting in the order you listed can produce incorrect results in some situations. For example, `#define GEN_FLAG_32(x) ((uint32_t) (1 << (x)))` when int is 16 bits on the target platform. This happened to me recently.

Comment: @ohitsderrick: Also, the behaviour is undefined if `int` is 32 bits and `x == 31`.